# How to create a Normalize Graph (Min Max Normalization) on Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I'm a newbie in Tableau. Data looks like that. I want to do Min Max Normalization.

```
Date            BU     BU Sub       Balance
03/30/2020     PBB  Construction    123,541
02/29/2020     CB      Land         9,801,312 
10/31/2019     REB     Finished     123,125,553
06/30/2018     PB     CRE           123,125,553
.....
```

The min max normalization formula is: (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) so I tried:

```
(ZN([balance]) - {FIXED: MIN(ZN([balance]))})
/
({FIXED: MAX(ZN([balance]))} - {FIXED: MIN(ZN([balance]))})
```

[Min Max Normalization Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoJWO.png)

I got a graph but I am not sure if it's normalize because I want growth in % by BU. And the y-axis number got so huge. In this formula, it should be in % but
the lowest number in the calc is 336. Does this mean it's 336% growth?

How do I make it more readable / interpret? Also, is this formula correct for doing Min Max Normalization? If not, what are other ways to do it on Tableau?

Answer (score 1):

This could be an aggregation issue - if you have more than one record per month the result of each will sum together, potentially creating a big number.

I suggest laying out your data in a table, using the month as the deepest level of aggregation, the same as within your chart, and see the results.

You could also aggregate the calculation within the calculation, however you'll still need to do the above with numbers in a table. In the table each value should be lined up with the sum at the end. [Measure Names / Measure Values](https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-display-measures-in-a-table/) is the way to do that. Link provided in case you don't know how to do that.

Your final formula may be something like:

```
SUM(ZN([balance])) - MIN({FIXED: MIN(ZN([balance]))})
/
MIN({FIXED: MAX(ZN([balance]))}) - MIN({FIXED: MIN(ZN([balance]))})
```

Please check the brackets.

I used MIN against all of the areas that should return a constant. You could also use MAX or AVG, it makes no difference.